# Detect network changes in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to detect when the user is online or offline.

I am using `CrossConnectivity` package to detect connectivity changes.

I have to connect to **VPN (Sonic Wall to be exact)** in order to connect to my server.

My problem is this: When I am connecting to my server, I need to switch apps in order for me to connect to my server. When I switch back to my app the function `SyncFunction.SyncUser(host, database, contact, ipaddress, pingipaddress)` is not executing. The connectivity changed function is not on my `App.xaml.cs` it is on my `Main Menu Content page` because I need the sync function to be executed in my main menu not the whole app. How can I fix this?

```cs
CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += async (sender, args) =>
{
    var appdate = Preferences.Get("appdatetime", String.Empty, "private_prefs");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appdate))
    {
        Preferences.Set("appdatetime", DateTime.Now.ToString(), "private_prefs");
    }
    else
    {
        if (DateTime.Now >= DateTime.Parse(Preferences.Get("appdatetime", String.Empty, "private_prefs")))
        {
            Preferences.Set("appdatetime", DateTime.Now.ToString(), "private_prefs");

            if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            {
                var ping = new Ping();
                var reply = ping.Send(new IPAddress(pingipaddress), 5000);

                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Syncing data to server";
                    lblStatus.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#2bcbba");

                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    SyncFunction.SyncUser(host, database, contact, ipaddress, pingipaddress);
                    lblStatus.Text = "Online - Connected to server";
                    lblStatus.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#2ecc71");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Online - Server unreachable. Connect to VPN";
                    lblStatus.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#e67e22");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Offline - Connect to internet";
                lblStatus.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#e74c3c");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Application Error", "It appears you change the time/date of your phone. Please restore the correct time/date", "Got it");
            await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Detecting connectivity change across a VPN is not easy.

A workaround solution is to use a webservice as ping.
If you have a backend with API, this "ping" can be executed regularly to ensure the network AND the API are accessible.

This solution is to be used in addition to the connectivity check

1. Subscribe to connectivity changed
2. When conectivity looks OK, check the "ping service"

Typically in a mob app, this "ping endpoint" can be something like "/about".
Moreover, this specific service can be use to perform the compatibility version check beetween App Mob version and API version.

(look also Xamarin.Essentials to replace CrossConnectivity by Xamarin.Essentials: Connectivity, https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)

Comment: Question: How can I know if my app is focused or not

Comment: Look the lifecyce of Xamarin.Forms application. You can use OnStart() / OnPause() / OnResume(). https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle

Comment: How can i add Onresume() on in MainMenu.xaml.cs

Comment: No, OnResume() is available only in App.xaml.cs. You can put your logic inside this class, or use a mechansim like Event or Messenger to notify your specific class.

Comment: Oh that is my problem, the change in network detection is not working when I for example connect to my server and I am in my other app and switch back